# DC motor specs from performance curve

Tags: motor, simulink

I'm trying to get a motor into a simulation (I'm using *Simulink*) but I don't have all the specs.

It is a 23 pole pair outrunner BLDC motor with 1600W and the performance curve is the following:
[image: Performannce curve]

I also have the datasheet with all the points in the graphic but nothing else (I don't have the motor with me to measure things out).

My *Simulink* model is the following, where \$R\$ stands for resistance, \$L\$ for inductance, \$U\$ for voltage, \$i\$ for current, \$K_t\$ for torque constant, \$T\$ for motor torque, \$T_L\$ for load torque, \$J\$ for inertia, \$\beta\$ for friction, \$\omega\$ for speed and \$K_e\$ for back emf constant (always using SI units - speed was converted to *rad/s*)
[image: model]

- **1st question**

The unknows that I want to find are \$R\$, \$\beta\$, \$K_e\$ and \$K_t\$ (I'm wild guessing \$J\$ and \$L\$ since in stationary state I can't find them), everything else is known.

So the plan was to separate the electrical equation \$ Ri + K_e\omega = U\$, the mechanical equation \$\beta\omega - iK_t = T_L\$ and the efficiency equation \$\eta = P_{out}/P_{in} = T_L\omega/Ui <=> \frac{T_L}{\beta}(iK_t-T_L)=\eta\frac{U}{R}(U-K_e\omega)\$.

I have 3 equations and 25 sets of points (from the graphic above), therefore 75 equaqtions and 4 unknowns so, to solve this overdetermined system I was using non-linear least squares method - *lsqnonlin()* - to obtain the most likely values for the unknown coefficients.

Is it a plausible way to solve this problem? I have tried to do this but can't seem to find good results after the saturation of the current. I only get a straight line for current and for speed.

- **2nd question**

If I'm using SI units, \$K_e\$ is supposed to be equal to \$K_t\$, but, due to the number of pole pairs, the electrical speed is not the same as the mechanical speed, so are these two constants still equal?

The speed that comes out of the model is the electrical speed and do I have to convert it to mechanical speed before the feedback? Or is the speed already the mechanical one?

*P.s:* Thanks for reading and sorry if I sounded confusing.

Comment: (That's a 1275 W motor: With electric machines (starting with transformers), rating power is output power.)

Comment: I'd just read Kt from the graph, and compute Ke directly from it. (You're only using the left 1/3 of the graph) Infer friction from Kt and the current at zero torque. torque. R you can infer from the decline in speed as torque (and thus current) increases : IR subtracts from the input voltage, reducing the voltage available to generate speed (use Ke)

Comment: @greybeard I was referring to the input power, I thought it was the rated power. Thank you

Comment: @user_1818839 could you explain a little better how are you doing it? Thank you in advance

Comment: (Note that the light blue curve doesn't reach the 1600 W grid line: nominal input seems to be 48 V, 32 A, 1536 W.)

Comment: re: electrical v mechanical speed : as long as you are consistent it shouldn't matter. Cross check that you aren't violating conservation of energy  : V * I = power ( * efficiency)  = speed * torque. Which bit didn't you understand?

Comment: @user_1818839 How do you read Kt from the graph (computing Ke from it means that it is equal?)

Comment: You have a graph of current vs torque : its slope is (A/Nm), you need Kt in Nm/A.

Comment: @user_1818839 But for which part of the graph? The ascendant part gives a different Kt from the saturated part

Comment: To repeat : (You're only using the left 1/3 of the graph)